# form validation with jquery and livevalidation

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation, livevalidation

I'm trying to do some form validation with livevaldation & jquery.

I've a formular with an input field like that:

```
<div id="prenameDiv" class="control-group">
     <input id="prename" name="prename" class="input-large" placeholder="Max"/>
</div>
```

So if there's an error on validation 'livevalidaton' adds the class 'LV_invalid_field' to the input - it looks like that:

```
<div id="prenameDiv" class="control-group">
    <input id="prename" name="prename" class="input-large LV_invalid_field" placeholder="Max"/>
</div>
```

That's ok,  but now I'll add another class 'error' to the div 'prenameDiv' when the DOM changes that it looks like that:

```
<div id="prenameDiv" class="control-group error">
     <input id="prename" name="prename" class="input-large LV_invalid_field" placeholder="Max"/>
</div>
```

I tried it that way:

```
if ($("#prenameDiv").bind("DOMSubtreeModified")){
     if ($("#prename").hasClass("LV_invalid_field")) {
         $("#prenameDiv").addClass("error");
     }
}
```

But nothing changes? Do you have some ideas?

Comment: read about code formatting first! Present your code properly (Write code after four spaces not within ``)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to achieve this.

```
if(($("#prenameDiv").find(".LV_invalid_field").length!=0)
{
   $("#prenameDiv").addClass("error");
}
```